# How to Setup Pingfederate for multi region HA or disaster recovery?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pingfederate, disaster-recovery

I have a Pingfederate SSO server working, but currently, it is serving traffic for other AWS regions as well. It would like to make it more reliable and HA in case of Amazon region going down. Any suggestions.

I check for Pingfederate cluster but not sure it can be setup for aws multi-region architecture.

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the [clustering guide](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf90/index.shtml#serverClusteringGuide/concept/pf_c_serverClusteringGuide.html) very carefully, paying specific attention to adaptive clustering, multi-region support, and dynamic discovery. Those things are in place in 9.0 specifically for AWS multi-region architectures with scalability in mind. Additionally, more features to be more AWS-friendly are coming in 9.1. After reviewing the clustering guide, you still have questions, you can come back here, edit your "question" to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewK. That was all the help needed. :)